# environmental variables in react js

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables

I want to use env variable to store my API keys and not have them hard coded and I couldnt find a  way to do it using React JS that worked for me. I tried creating a .env file and trying to access them using `process.env.NAME_OF_ENV_VAR` but nothing displays when i try to display it in a

tag or log it to the console.

Comment: I recommend you to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dotenv

Answer (score 0):

in react env are defined with prefix `REACT_APP_<NAME>`
eg: `process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY`

Answer (score 0):

To use env variables in react js like you'd use in a regular JavaScript project you have to install a different nom package tailored to work with react apps called `react-dotenv`. Credit to @Guiditox for linking commenting the resource.